# numpy.random.permutation lose a column

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

First of all sorry but I haven't great programming skills, I'm learning Python for my master thesis in Natural Sciences.

In my script there's this piece of code:

```
self._dumpArrayToFile(movers, 'movers_'+str(y)+'_'+str(r)+'.csv')
moversCats = numpy.random.permutation(movers['cat'])
self._dumpArrayToFile(moversCats, 'movers_'+str(y)+'_'+str(r)+'_shuffled.csv')
```

the first line prints out a .csv file with two columns, the second line shuffle the array by the first column (`cat`) and the last line prints out the shuffled file; the problem is that the shuffled file has only one column, i.e the `cat` column

How can I shuffle the array without losing the second column?

Comment: the researcher who's working at the script with me already tries to shuffle whole movers array but that gave some errors, i.e duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing a single column to `permutation`, so that is all that gets shuffled. Per [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

> If `x` is a multi-dimensional array, it is only shuffled along its first index.

The example clearly shows what this means:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
>>> np.random.permutation(arr)
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Note the rows' contents stay the same, but they are randomly reordered. You can therefore pass the whole array, rather than just the `cat` column:

```
moversCats = numpy.random.permutation(movers)
```